# Excel 2010 VB Script – Highlight Row Issue

Tags: vb.net, excel, row, highlight

I was wondering if someone had any suggestions to this. I want the row to highlight below row 6 when a cell is clicked on. So if I click on A7, then row 7 will highlight. If I then click on B9, row 7 will have the highlight removed and row 9 will then highlight. I did find code that does work for what I need and have customized it a little. Everything works exactly the way I need it to work, except for when Excel is saved, closed out, and reopened.

If row 9 is highlighted, and the spreadsheet is saved, closed, and reopened, row 9 will remain highlighted (even when another cell is clicked on). So now I have 2 rows highlighted. In order to fix this once the spreadsheet is opened back up is to click on a different row and then click back on row 9. Then it will be back to 1 highlighted row.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Below is the code that I am using.

Thanks for any help someone can provide,

Chris

`Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`

ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Static rr

If rr <> "" Then
    With Rows(rr).Interior
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
End If

r = Selection.Row
rr = r

With Rows(r).Interior
    .ColorIndex = 20
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With

ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own code instead of trying to work with the code I found. This works a lot better. It also allows the user to specify their own range of rows to highlight.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect

Dim iFirstCol As Integer
Dim iLastCol As Integer
Dim iFirstRow As Integer
Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim iColor As Integer

'''Only adjust the below numbers to fit your desired results.'''
iFirstCol = 1 'Change this number to the number of the first column that needs to be highlighted. Column A = 1.
iLastCol = 15 'Change this number to the number of the last column that needs to be highlighted. Column A = 1.
iFirstRow = 7 'Change this number to the number of the first row that needs to be highlighted.
iLastRow = 500 'Change this number to the number of the last row that needs to be highlighted.
iColor = 20 'Change this number to use a different highlight color.
'''End of changes, do not change anything else.'''

'The row highlight will only be applied if the selected range is within this if statement criteria.
If Target.Row > iFirstRow - 1 And Target.Row < iLastRow + 1 And Target.Column > iFirstCol - 1 And Target.Column < iLastCol + 1 Then

    'Resets the color within the full range when cell selection changed.
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(iFirstRow, iFirstCol), ActiveSheet.Cells(iLastRow, iLastCol)).Interior.Color = xlNone

    'Applies the colors to the row.
    For counter = iFirstCol To iLastCol
        With ActiveSheet.Cells(Target.Row, iFirstCol).Interior
            .ColorIndex = iColor
            .Pattern = xlSolid
        End With
        iFirstCol = iFirstCol + 1
    Next counter

End If

ActiveSheet.Protect
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, and nice to see the more meaningful variable names ;) Andy.

Answer (score 1):

The following combination of code seems to be working; I'm highlighting the entire row each time.

```
Private lastRow As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    lastRow = ActiveCell.Row
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If lastRow <> 0 Then
        Rows(lastRow).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        If Target.Row > 6 Then
            Target.Rows(1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 20
        End If
        lastRow = Target.Row
    Else
        lastRow = Target.Row
    End If
End Sub
```

Actually, it probably needs a bit of work. However, it might be a starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, sorry about my code. I can't get it to display correctly in here, even though in edit mode it is correct. I tried to use this code you provided. I am still having the same issue. If you save it, close out, and reopen it, it still will have 2 rows highlighted. In your code you actually need to click on a cell once, then the highlight starts working once you click on a second cell, it doesn't seem to be working right away until you make a first click. Thanks

Comment: OK, I corrected the code in my post, it should work now. I discovered that I had the <pre> and <code> commands switched around. I mean it works as far as you should be able to copy it now, it still has the issue when it is saved, closed, and reopened, causing two lines to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Your static rr variable is a Variant and will not have a default value of "". So, when you re-open the file, the cursor will be in the row it was in previously, and because rr is not equal to "" it will not remove the highlight from this line. (In fact, I'm not sure how it is removing the highlight currently.)

Anyway, try:

```
Static rr
If IsEmpty(rr) Then
    rr = ""
End If
```

Alternatively, give rr the data-type of Integer or Long, which will assume a default value of 0.

Comment: BTW unprotecting and protecting the worksheet every time the cursor is moved seems like a lot of unnecessary processing. If it needs to be unprotected then surely you could just supply the password to do this.

Comment: Also, your code is incorrect, and I assume you meant If rr = "" Then, but if I amend to this then it still produces an error.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the post but it doesn't seem to change any as far as how it works. I added that in addition to what I have.

Comment: Well, there is a lot of other code in the spreadsheet other than this and the spreadsheet is protected for other reasons. In order for the highlight to work, without an error, I first need to unprotect it. Otherwise, yes there wouldn't be a point to unprotect and protect it. I am just running this in a new test spreadsheet with nothing else in it at all, just trying to get the row thing to work when it is saved and reopened. Once it is implemented I will need to have the unprotect in there, but for this testing there is no need for it. Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me with or without the amendment. A quick fix is to highlight the whole sheet and create a Conditional Formatting rule with this formula =CELL("row")=CELL("row",A1). This will highlight the whole row with a chosen colour, but you would need to press F9 after clicking into a cell (or type something and press Tab). The formula could be amended to only apply to rows beyond 6. Alternatively, there are plug-ins available. You can achieve this yourself with some code but it requires a little more than your current code.

Comment: Your right the code isn't working from here. I see why. The code shows correctly in edit mode on this page, but then is not showing correctly in the final viewable post. Like this line should be If rr <> "" Then and not how it is displayed, it is missing the <>.

Comment: I got it to work. Well, in most cases this would not be the best way to do it. However, it works for my needs. I used this code of yours with mine, then I added this line in your If statement ActiveSheet.Range("A7:O500").Interior.Color = xlNone. I use that same line in my spreadsheet already, so it fits in this case and works for my needs. If other people was to use this though it wouldn't be practical. I don't think I would have got this to work though without those 3 lines of your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I often highlight rows in tables on selection. While I might be over-simplifying things it seems so much easier then the code you have provided above.
Here is what I do;
I use just a tiny big of code in the Worksheet selection change for the range that should have the highlighting rows in effect, such as this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D8:R10000")) Is Nothing Then
Range("B1").Value = ActiveCell.Row
End If
End Sub
```

Then I use a Conditional formatting for B1 and the range, with any type of formatting you might like for the selected row. A Conditional formatting formula for the above would be:
=$B$1=ROW()
with an Applied To range of: =$D$8:$R$10000

That's it. No other coding is required and formats can be changed simply.
What are your thoughts on this?