# Issue with Copying Excel Cells

Tags: excel, vbscript, copy

I am not sure if there is a solution to this issue. In Excel when you copy a cell the border starts moving/flashing. Only when that border is moving you are allowed to paste its contents into another cell. Once the border is no longer moving, you are also unable to paste its contents. The other option is to double click on the cell or go into the formula bar to manually copy the data, which then you can paste as much as you want, at least until something else is copied.

Here is my problem. I have script within the “Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)” section of my worksheet. So every time another cell is selected this script is run. The script works perfectly and I do not need this changed. The spreadsheet first needs to be unlocked before the script can run, so I had to put this at the top of the script “ActiveSheet.Unprotect” and this at the bottom “ActiveSheet.Protect”. When I select a different cell and the code hits either the unprotect or the protect commands, then the copied cell border is no longer flashing, so I can’t paste.

Is there a script of some sort that I can use so it retains the copied data? The script should only run when a cell is copied. I also don’t want to use the SendKeys function because that typically causes more issues then what it solves. I have always been wondering where Excel stores its data for copied cells, since usually copied data is stored in the windows clipboard, or some other dumping ground since Windows 7 & 8 no longer use the clipboard for copping data. So I don’t understand why Excel doesn’t use the same method as everything else when a cell is copied.

This isn’t too much of an issue, more of an annoyance than anything. If someone should have a solution to this please let me know, but I don’t think there is one.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Excel has never respected standard Windows clipboard behavior.  I have never read a satisfactory explanation why you can only paste once and can't paste at all if you do anything *other than* paste after the copy.

Comment: There are several actions that cancel a copy operation. `Protect` and `Unprotect` are 2 of them. I don't think there's a way to prevent that, so you'll have to work around it. What is the actual problem you want to solve by copying the cell?

Comment: It's just a general issue just in the fact that cells can’t be copied, like by using the Ctrl + C buttons, because as soon as another cell is selected it removes the copy on the cell. Here is my code that I am using. I don't need this changed, it works great. View the one with the checkmark on it as the answer, which I wrote. For this section of code the unprotect is not needed, but due to the other code in other sections it protects the sheet, so I have to unprotect it in this section otherwise it will error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005931/excel-2010-vb-script-highlight-row-issue